# Assembly ,which is the best data type for signed ints ranging from -256 to 255?

Tags: assembly, byte, signed

In the .bss section of the assembly code, I am confused if what i should do is...

```
var resw 1
```

or

```
var resb 2
```

if I am planning to store signed values ranging from -256 to 255 on the said variable.

Comment: There's no point in intentionally lying about the data size and having to provide a size override to back up the lie.  That just produces bugs.

Comment: is var resb 2 going to be sufficient enough?

Comment: Not what I said.  Try it both ways, you're bound to learn something.

Comment: It wouldn't really matter much. When you have a `reg,mem` or `mem,reg` operand pair, the size is typically determined by the register, and when you have a `mem,imm` operand pair you typically have to explicitly state the size anyway.